# How to dynamically hide selective Column headers in MUI Grid

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I have a MUI table grid with checkbox enabled.
Upon certain selection I would like to hide column headers and overlay it with another set of buttons.

But I would like to keep the select all checkbox visible to users.

Currently in my datagrid config I am using

```
slots=
{{
          columnHeaders: () => null,
        }}
```

which hides the entire column header including the select all checkbox.

How can I hide all headers except the checkbox.